# How to call a razor partial view in aspx view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a razor partial view. I want to use it in an aspx view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `RenderPartial()` cannot call a different view engine, but using `RenderPage()` will allow you to use a different view engine.

**Edit**:
Looks like you should have no problems rendering an aspx view in a razor page using RenderPartial()

Comment: @Michael Kennedy - Actually, I think you're right, I've got an aspx partial view now rendering on my razor page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your action method return a "PartialViewResult", it will know how to render whatever partial you return, either ascx or razor. It's all HTML in the end.